# Syntax error when the developer friendly name starts with a number

Tags: api, collegescorecard, json

I’m having an issue with this line –

`obj.results[0][2017].admissions.sat_scores.25th_percentile.math`

It’s giving me a syntax error. I’m using Javascript and it seems to be having a problem with the number 25. This code works just fine –

`obj.results[0][2017].admissions.sat_scores.average.overall`

Any line that reads `admissions.sat_scores.[NUMBER]` throws an error. What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the way I tried to access that property. Since the key name starts with a number, I need to use brackets. This expression works.

obj.results[0][2017].admissions.sat_scores["25th_percentile"].math;